# Changing background colour of an Activity based on a theme/style

Tags: android, android-activity, background, themes, styles

I have an Activity which has a style resource set in the manifest (using `android:theme="@style/blah"`. I wish to dynamically change the background colour of this Activity in Java code. How would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/activityRootContainer>

</FrameLayout>
```

Then in your code:

```
findViewById(R.id.activityRootContainer).setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.backgroundImage))
```

or

```
findViewById(R.id.activityRootContainer).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
```

HTH?

Comment: Cheers, that worked. I was going to try a similar way but with a LinearLayout, but this looks neater.